# After entering a value for dimensions Blender shows zero

Tags: 3d-view

I have a plane and when I enter a value in the Z dimension Blender shows me the value zero. Simply said I cannot enter a value in the Z dimension of this plane. But when I change the value of the Y dimension then in the viewport the Z dimension is changed. Anyone ?

[image]

As you can probably see the Z dimension of the plane is 10m but in the properties panel Blender says that the Y dimension is 10m

[image]

Comment: It is because the object is rotated (around X here). So Z/-Y swap in global view, and dimensions are given in local view.

Comment: @lemon is there a way to fix this because it is really silly I think

Comment: @lemon I should have applied the Rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimensions are given in local view and your object is rotated around X. A way to see that is to activate the axis display option:

[image]

If you want to avoid that, the only way I know is what you stated in the comments: applying the rotation.